# How to filter 1 view with two fields based on 1 contextual filter?

Tags: 7, views

I having a view which result in a table with three fields like:

```
                 field1, field2,field3
row1 with values 100,    110,   503
row2 with values 200,    520,   110
row3 with values 300,    530,   210
```

All numbers are nid. All fields are in different node types.
I'm calling /foo?nodeid=110.

I'm trying to setup a view so that row3 is not displayed anymore and I can eventually have a table with row1 and row2 with the values of field1.

I tried a lot but do not get it. If I have one contextual filter I can filter the table on field2 and if I have another contextual filter I can filter on field3. But I cannot combine them like a normal filter like and/or.

Any suggestion how to solve this?

**Note**: For now my view is a table but in the end I will use it under webform so it then will be a webform display with a webform selection list.

Comment: What is your views FORM, is it Table, Grid?

Comment: For now it is a table but in the end I will  use it under webform so it then will be a webform display with a webform selection list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Views Argument Substitutions](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_argument_substitutions). It lets you use contextual filter values in the regular filters.

1. Add a **Global: Null** contextual filter to get your default value. It's very important to use Global: Null so the view isn't filtered.
2. In your regular filters, you can add that value with * * * 1 * * * (no spaces) so that you can add AND / OR stuff. Use a different number if your Global: Null isn't at the top of the contextual filter list.

Answer (score 0):

If you can achieve this using normal filter, you should go for that. You can fine-tune your Normal filter by creating new filter group in filter and then you can use And/Or inside one group of filters and in-between the filter groups. You can refer the first image in answer of this question [Excluding Book children from a Custom view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207722/excluding-book-children-from-a-custom-view) as an example.